# concatenate tokens in lexer: need to create gtype_enum genum_abc

Tags: concatenation, antlr4, lexer

I need, for user of DSL to be able to define an ENUm in this format... (or something similar)

```
gtype_enum genum_NameOfMyEnum { "abc", "xyz", "pqr" };
```

Here are the lines from .g4

```
// Parser:

 enum_def : GTYPE_ENUM EQ LCURLY enum_val (COMMA, enum_val)* RCURLY SEMICOLON;
    enum_val : STRING ;

 // Lexer:

    ENUM_TYPE: 'gtype_enum' ;
    GTYPE_ENUM : ENUM_TYPE 'genum_'(ID) ;

    ID: (ALPHA) (ALPHA|NUM|'_')* ;
```

Basically conveyed the intent of `concatenation between 'genum_' and a valid ID`, visually;
And that of course is not going to help the Lexer see things my way :)  ... and it isn't.

So, how do I convey my intent of concatenation to the Lexer?
Am OK moving some Lexer tokenizing into Parser rules, if it achieves the goal).

Answer (score 1):

A slightly modified version like this works.
Basically I made the `ENUM_TYPE` a fragment, meaning it will only be part of a token and not a token itself (otherwise there would never be a `GTYPE_ENUM` token) and added whitespace token to the `GTYPE_ENUM` token.

```
// Parser:

 enum_def : GTYPE_ENUM EQ LCURLY enum_val (COMMA enum_val)* RCURLY SEMICOLON;
    enum_val : STRING ;

 // Lexer:

    fragment ENUM_TYPE: 'gtype_enum' ;
    GTYPE_ENUM : ENUM_TYPE WS+ 'genum_'(ID) ;

    ID: (ALPHA) (ALPHA|NUM|'_')* ;

    ALPHA : [a-zA-Z];
    NUM : [0-9];
    STRING : '"' (~["])*'"';
    COMMA : ',';
    LCURLY : '{';
    RCURLY : '}';
    SEMICOLON : ';';
    EQ : '=';
    WS : ' ' -> skip;
```

Note that your sample is missing an `=` before the `{`.

[image: parse result]

I would prefer the following grammar though, which moves some part of the work from lexer to parser:

```
// Parser:

    enum_def : GTYPE_ENUM EQ LCURLY enum_val (COMMA enum_val)* RCURLY SEMICOLON;
    enum_val : STRING ;
    gtype_enum : ENUM_TYPE GTYPE_ENUM_NAME ;

 // Lexer:

    ENUM_TYPE: 'gtype_enum' ;
    GTYPE_ENUM_NAME : 'genum_'(ID) ;

    ID: (ALPHA) (ALPHA|NUM|'_')* ; // maybe make also fragment

    ALPHA : [a-zA-Z];
    NUM : [0-9];
    STRING : '"' (~["])*'"';
    COMMA : ',';
    LCURLY : '{';
    RCURLY : '}';
    SEMICOLON : ';';
    EQ : '=';
    WS : ' ' -> skip;
```